# Trying to convert a .py to .exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have one script to convert from .py to .exe but it keeps giving me the error as shown in the snippet.

I have 23 scripts to convert and I have 22 converted but this one wont convert. I have used pyinstaller. I am not sure why its giving me the error because the script in question does exist and it is in the directory where all the other .py scripts reside.

[image]

Comment: did you try with copy-paste name of the script? Maybe there are some strange chars that you can't see...

Comment: I have tried. I will try again

Comment: No it doesnt work.

Comment: Its strange as all the other scripts converted to exe successfully

Comment: Hey, Nevermind. I fixed it. I just downloaded another copy from my Google Drive that I had saved and used that one and It converted successfully.